# Why LoadString returns the concatenated strings from the resources?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, winapi, resources

MS Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise; C++.

Into my console project I added the RC-file (i.e. resource) and added two strings into it:

[image]

I wrote such function for getting of the strings:

```
PCTSTR LoadString(HMODULE h, DWORD id) {
    h = NULL == h ? GetModuleHandle(NULL) : h;
    PTSTR copyright = NULL;
    LoadString(h, id, (PTSTR)&copyright, 0); // This is WinAPI function
    return copyright;
}
```

Now I try to use it in my code:

```
// Set necessary locale
PCTSTR lang = LoadString(NULL, IDS_STRING_LOCALE);
_wsetlocale(LC_ALL, lang);

// Print copyright info
PCTSTR copyright = LoadString(NULL, IDS_STRING_COPYRIGHT);
if (NULL != copyright) {
    // TODO: unexpected string output is here!
    wcout << copyright << endl;
}
else {
    DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
```

The `lang` variable has right value: `Russian_Russia.1251`, but the `copyright` variable has the`Hello, World!Russian_Russia.1251` instead of `Hello World!`.

Why does it happen?

Comment: shouldn't you be allocating memory for PSTR copyright in LoadString method?

Comment: Read MSDN description, looks like it could be used to read raw resources without pre-allocating buffers. However, nowhere it says resources are null-terminated - and it seems like it is what happening here.

Comment: Fom MSDN: `If this parameter is 0, then lpBuffer receives a read-only pointer to the resource itself.`

Comment: I think you are getting pointers to the raw data which does not include the null terminators.

Comment: Look my previous comment about the MSDN, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> PTSTR copyright = NULL;
> LoadString(h, id, (PTSTR)&copyright, 0); // This is WinAPI function
> ```

You are invoking the Win32 `LoadString()` function passing `0` as the value of the last parameter. As you can read from the [MSDN documentation of `LoadString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486(v=vs.85).aspx), when the last parameter is 0:

> [...] If this parameter is 0, then lpBuffer receives a read-only pointer to the resource itself.

So, on successful return from `LoadString()`, the `copyright` pointer in your code is set by `LoadString()` to point to the string resource itself.

However, string resources are *not* NUL terminated by default; they are length prefixed.
So, since your string is not NUL terminated, when you print it using `wcout`, the characters following the copyright string are printed as well. So you get the whole `Hello, World!Russian_Russia.1251` string.

To fix that, instead of using raw C-like string pointers, you can build a `std::wstring` from the string loaded from resources, and just use it with `wcout`. Note that the resource string's length is the return value of `LoadString()`.
[For example:](http://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2010/01/05/stl-strings-loading-from-resources/)

```
std::wstring LoadStringFromResource(
    _In_ UINT stringID,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE instance = nullptr )
{
    WCHAR * pBuf = nullptr;

    int len = LoadStringW(
        instance,
        stringID,
        reinterpret_cast< LPWSTR >( &pBuf ),
        0 );

    if( len )
        return std::wstring( pBuf, len );
    else
        return std::wstring();
}
```

Or you could use the **`CString`** class from ATL/MFC, and its convenient methods ([`CString::LoadString()` overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a44fb3wy.aspx)) or [proper constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cws1zdt8.aspx) to load a string from resources.
Iin this case, the complexity of the `LoadString()` call is hidden under the hood, under the implementation of `CString`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I fixed my code. Look my answer, please. In my previous code I expected that each string in the resource file is terminated by `\0`.

Comment: @AndreyBushman: In your code, you don't need to call `LoadString()` twice. Once you have called it the first time, and have a pointer to the string, if you insist on using raw C-like string buffers/pointers, then you can just `memcpy()` from the original pointer to the allocated destination buffer. But IMO in C++ it's much better to use string **classes** (instead of C-like buffers/pointers).

Answer (score 0):

Resource strings are only null-terminated if you explicitly null-terminate them. In order for your code, which assumes null-termination, to work, you should null-terminate the strings. In the .rc file, instead of

```
"Hello, World!"
```

write

```
"Hello, World!\0"
```

Comment: I tried this already, before I created my topic. It didn't help me.

Comment: How could that possibly be true?

Comment: I tried to add `\0` to my strings in the VS text editor, but when I recompiled my code I saw what it didn't help me. The character added by me disappeared.

Comment: I tried to do the same through the text resources table, but the character `\0`added by me disappeared also.

Comment: I expected each string in the resource table is broken by `\0` char, therefore it is enough to pass `0` in the last parameter of the `LoadString` (the WinAPI  function) and to get the pointer of the string in the resources. I see I was mistaken.

Comment: You must have got something wrong. It's perfectly possible to null terminate these strings.

Comment: The RC (resource compiler) has a command-line option to Null terminate all strings in the string table: '/n'. It is possible to set this option in the property pages of the vcxproj project. If you enable this option it isn't necessary to manually add '\0' to a resource string yourself.

Comment: What worked for me, was using `\x0000` instead of `\0`. I think this is because I'm using `LoadStringW` along with other multibyte functions.

Comment: @itachi I think it's less about how the strings are loaded, and more about how they are specified in the resource file. The compiled resource always stores strings as Unicode I believe.

Answer (score -2):

Oh, I fixed my code. Now it works fine:

```
PTSTR LoadString(HMODULE h, DWORD id) {
    h = NULL == h ? GetModuleHandle(NULL) : h;
    PTSTR ptr = NULL;   
    // it returns really length instead of concatenated 
    // string length, therefore I can use it for malloc.
    int i = LoadString(h, id, (PTSTR)&ptr, 0);
    if (0 == i) {
        return NULL;
    }
    PTSTR string = (PTSTR)malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    LoadString(h, id, string, i + 1);
    return string; // don't forget free resource in the outer code.
}
```

The strings in the resources are not separated through the `\0` char as I expected.

Comment: If you use this code, make sure the caller calls `free()` on the returned pointer to release the memory: `PCTSTR lang = LoadString(NULL, IDS_STRING_LOCALE); ... free(lang);` and likewise for `copyright`. Otherwise, instead of using `malloc()` (or `new[]`), it is better to use `std::string` or `std::wstring` (or even `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`) as demonstrated in Mr.C64's answer.

Comment: You allocation allocates too many characters and does not null terminate. This code is very broken.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan,  I am learning C\C++ and I don't see the mistake. Can you expand your notice for me? Why `PTSTR string = (PTSTR)malloc(i * (sizeof(TCHAR) + 1));` is wrong in your opinion?

Comment: You can work that out yourself surely. Try substituting in some values for `i` and see what happens.

Comment: I am thinking you are not right about my `PTSTR string = (PTSTR)malloc(i * (sizeof(TCHAR) + 1));`  code row. Sorry.

Comment: You are meant to allocate `i+1` characters. You did not. You allocated `i` elements whose size is one larger than the size of a character. Your code will fail when `i` is zero. You are really making a meal of this. Let me give you some advice. You are a self-confessed beginner. Your knowledge is incomplete. All that is fine. But you should be less confident in your own abilities. Have more self-doubt.

Comment: Thank you, David. Now I see my mistake. I will rewrite it to this: `PTSTR string = (PTSTR)malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));`. And thank you for your advice. I didn't want to offend you. I appologize.